# How I can Hide "this may cost you money"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I am developing native android app using **Eclipse**, I add the following permission on Android Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Then, I get the following message when I am trying to  install the android app on my device:

> Directly call phone numbers  this may cost you money

could I do something to hide this message because I think this is not friendly for users? **maybe i need to use another permission, which is the closer one with no permission is required?**

I used the following code on my adapter:

```
   public void onClick(View v) { 
           Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
           callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(PhoneCall));
           v.getContext().startActivity(callIntent); }
       });
```

Comment: Nope, you cannot deal with that. Maybe you're a fair developer, but there are a lot who is not really fair..

Comment: actually i develop an app display list of blood category with full name and phone number ..then i allow user to call phone number directly from list view

Comment: you can instead just make an intent to populate phone number, and make the user hit the call button. then you could preserve functionality and get rid of the call phone permission

Comment: could you please give me code instead of    public void onClick(View v) { 
               //do something
                 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(PhoneCall));
            v.getContext().startActivity(callIntent); 
           //  notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
       });

Comment: @dabluck question updated to avoid votes down ..thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are welcome to remove the `CALL_PHONE` permission. Then the message will not appear when the app is installed. All permissions trigger installation warnings, not just `CALL_PHONE`.

Note that your app only needs the `CALL_PHONE` permission if you use stuff like the `ACTION_CALL` `Intent`. `ACTION_DIAL` can also be used to place phone calls, but since it allows the user to be involved, no permission is required.

*EDIT*

Use this format to specify the number and user will have only to click green button "Call".

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: actually i used this code :   public void onClick(View v) { 
               //do something
                 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(PhoneCall));
            v.getContext().startActivity(callIntent); 
           //  notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
       });

Comment: @MohamadMahmoud: Correct. My point is that if you switch from `ACTION_CALL` to `ACTION_DIAL`, then you no longer need the permission.